# DUVIDA SELECT COM INNER JOIN E COUNT

Tags: mysql, select, join

Ola,sou relativamente novo quando o assunto e banco de dados e preciso gerar um relatório com as seguintes informações,mas não estou conseguindo alguém poderia me dar uma luz por favor:

Nome do cliente

Qtd de compras realizadas por cada cliente

Total em R$ das compras de cada cliente

Qtd de compras realizadas no ano atual de cada cliente

Total em R$ das compras no ano atual de cada cliente

Foto do perfil (foto com ordem_foto = 1)

considerando apenas compras com o status (sel_status_compra) concluido

com as seguintes tabelas

tabela clientes_fotos:
[image: Tabela clientes][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tabela compras acima

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tabela itenscompra acima

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tabela clientes acima

Comment: Passe o esquema das tabelas como texto.

Answer (score 2):

Não vi nenhum campo do tipo data para filtrar a data das compras pelo ano, mas tentei deixar a query mais próxima possível. Tenta aí no seu computador e ajuste o que for necessário.

```
select 
    cli.nome_cliente, 
    count(c.id_compra), 
    sum(ic.valor_itemc),
    count(sra.id), 
    sum(sra.valor),
    cf.url_foto
from cliente cli
    inner join compras c on cli.id_cliente = c.fk_id_cliente_clientes
    inner join itenscompra ic on ic.fk_id_compra = c.id_compra
    left join (select * from clientes_fotos where ordem_foto = 1) cf on cf.fk_id_cliente_clientes = cli.id_cliente
    left join (select compras.fk_id_clientes_clientes, compras.id_compra, sum(itenscompra.valor_itemc) as valor
                from compras 
                    inner join itenscompra on itenscompra.fk_id_compra = compras.id_compra
                where year(compras.**ALGUM CAMPO DATA NA TABELA COMPRAS**)=2019 and compras.sel_status_compra = "Concluido"
                group by compras.id_compra) sra on cli.id_cliente = sra.fk_id_cliente_clientes
where
    c.sel_status_compra = "Concluido"
group by cli.nome_cliente, cf.url_foto
```

Comment: muti obrigado irmão,fiz os ajustes e funcionou aqui.